# What type of damage accounts for bleeding damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-types

I am writing a feat for D&D 5E, one of the minor features is that the feat causes a creature hit by your critical Slashing weapon attack to receive ongoing bleeding damage until some time has passed or they receive healing. This damage has no effect against Constructs, Undead or Elementals.

What damage type would be dealt from bleeding? Would it be slashing damage, as that is what caused it? Or something else?

Comment: Answers that are of the form *“Well, the strict answer is such-and-so. However, a feat is not a good idea for these reasons: XYZ”* are still answers. As such, they do belong in answer posts rather than in comments, so that the community can provide feedback in the form of up/down votes and constructive comments, which isn't possible when such answers are posted as comments. I've cleaned up the answers in comments here so far.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**It doesn't need to have a damage type.**

Example from the Stirge *Blood drain* ability (MM 284):

> ***Blood Drain***. Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, reach 5 ft., one creature. Hit: 5 (1d4 + 3) piercing damage, and the stirge attaches to the target. While attached, the stirge doesn't attack. Instead, at the start of each of the stirge's turns, the target loses 5 (1d4 + 3) **hit points due to blood loss**.

Comment: I'd written a whole answer, but this is way better. You could also mention the Bearded Devil's Glaive attack or the Horned Devil's Tail, which are similar and likewise have no damage type.

Comment: Is hit point loss necessarily the same thing as taking damage? The attack doesn't refer to blood loss as damage, but it does to the base attack. This is not true of the devil wounds, however.

Answer (score 9):

## Match the type of the weapon

Under this rule, a slashing weapon makes a "slashing wound". Damage from bleeding out of a slashing wound is still slashing damage. This makes sense because a creature with resistance to slashing damage should receive a smaller wound and bleed less. The same logic applies for piercing and bludgeoning damage.

Answer (score 8):

## Use necrotic damage

*Necrotic* is the damage type for attacks that decay or weaken the body. From a flavor standpoint, it may not be an exact match, but it's the closest single damage type of the 13 listed in the books.

The Sword of Wounding (DMG p207) is an example of this:

> At the start of each of the wounded creature's turns, it takes 1d4 necrotic damage for each time you've wounded it, and it can then make a DC 15 Constitution saving throw, ending the effect of all such wounds on itself on a success

Comment: The Sword of Wounding might be an example worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel untyped damage is likely the best for this, resistance is often something that is limited to how hard it is to inflict damage, this doesn't mean that would necessarily bleed less, and with the possibility of vulnerability and depending on how you handled the amount of damage it could be something a bit more abused. Necrotic strikes me more of a magical nature rather than a bleeding wound and since it is specifically blood loss causing it, well, it would technically be bleed damage.

I'd simply go with untyped and undead, construct and elementals are immune but be careful how you work with damage and how further damage is applied. What one could do is make the bleed for X damage and have x be the attribute associated and have the DC be a flat amount.