# Can a Zealot Barbarian apply Radiant rage damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, barbarian, damage-types, rage

[Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#ClassFeatures) says:

> When you make a melee weapon attack using Strength, you gain a bonus to the damage roll that increases as you gain levels as a barbarian, as shown in the Rage Damage column of the Barbarian table.

The [Zealot Barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot)'s Divine Fury feature says:

> At 3rd level, while you're raging, the first creature you hit on each of your turns with a weapon attack takes extra damage equal to 1d6 + half your barbarian level. The extra damage is necrotic or radiant; you choose the type of damage when you gain this feature.

Can the rage damage be radiant/necrotic, or does it have to be part of the weapon's damage die? Is Divine Fury part of the weapon damage die?

Comment: Related: "[What type of damage is Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62181)" and "[Can I choose which damage type my Sneak Attack does if my weapon does multiple types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103132)" and perhaps "[Can a Barbarian choose which weapon die to add for his Brutal Critical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127429)" and "[If the attack or spell that the goblin's Fury of the Small trait is applied to deals multiple types of damage, what type is the extra damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116731)"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Only the extra damage from Divine Fury is necrotic or radiant.

The [Divine Fury](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot) feature specifies exactly which damage is necrotic or radiant:

> While you’re raging, the first creature you hit on each of your turns with a weapon attack takes **extra damage** equal to 1d6 + half your barbarian level. The **extra damage** is necrotic or radiant.

Only the damage from this feature is necrotic or radiant. “Extra damage” here is very obviously referring to the extra damage *from this feature*, defined in the sentence before.

Since it says nothing about *changing* the type of any damage, it does not change the type of any damage, and the bonus damage from rage is of the damage type of the weapon being used.

Further, “extra” means “in addition to”, so it is damage that is added to whatever damage the attack does without the class feature, and without the class feature, the rage damage is of the type of the weapon used.