# Damage calculation for a multi-typed sneak attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack

I play a level 7 Arcane Trickster Rogue with a Shadow Blade equipped which deals 2d8 **Psychic damage**.  In addition I used Absorb Elements with which I absorbed an Ice Mephit's Frost Breath on me, which would add 1d6 **Cold damage** to that attack. Lastly I cast Green-Flame-Blade to finally make my attack which would add 1d8 **Fire damage**.

As the Ice Mephit is resistant to Cold but weak to Fire, I get that the additional damage from Absorb Elements would be halved, but Green-Flame-Blade would be doubled.
Now to the sneak Attack:

> Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe's distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

As the Sneak attack inherits the weapon attack's type, how would I calculate the damage for the sneak attack?

1. Do I choose which type the sneak attack is?
2. Is it all types at once, and I count the amount of time an element is resisted or is strong against the enemy? (in this case 1. resistance and 1 vulnerability would neutralise and I'd just take the normal result from my sneak attack die)
3. Does the damage calculation go by whatever type is more beneficial to a) the attacker or b) the defender?

Comment: Related: [What Type of Damage is Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62181/what-type-of-damage-is-sneak-attack)

Comment: Related (at least): "[Can I choose which damage type my Sneak Attack does if my weapon does multiple types?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103132)" and "[When a ranged attack deals multiple damage types, can I choose what damage type my Sharpshooter bonus gives?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/178020)" and "[Can a Zealot Barbarian apply Radiant rage damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/172777)" and "[If the attack or spell that the goblin's Fury of the Small trait is applied to deals multiple types of damage, what type is the extra damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116731)"

Comment: Also related: "[Can a Barbarian choose which weapon die to add for his Brutal Critical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/127429)" and "[What type of damage is Sneak Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62181)"

Comment: I have closed your question as I feel it has effectively been asked before. This isn't a bad thing though, a duplicate question actually helps people find answers. That said, if you feel your question is not a duplicate, that it has not been answered in the [marked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103132), feel free to [edit] or leave a comment explaining why. Your question can always be reopened. You also do not need to signal your edits. But where are my manners? Welcome to RPG.SE! Feel free to take the [tour] or visit the [help] for further guidance. Best of luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Also worth noting is that the specific combination of *shadow blade* and *green-flame blade* may not work, or is up to the GM. We have a question on this interaction actually: "[Can the blade created by Shadow Blade be used with the Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade cantrips?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177347)"